# Is it possible to rmarkdown::render a pdf_document for kable tables with styling?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr, kable

I'm trying to render a Rmd file in a script:

`rmarkdown::render("Test.Rmd")`

Which works fine when I knit the file itself but if it contains kable_styling options at all e.g.

````
```{r, echo = FALSE}
library(kableExtra)
dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6]
kable(dt, align = "c", format="latex", booktabs=T) %>% 
  kable_styling(latex_options=c("striped", "scale_down"), font_size = 7, html_font = "Times New Roman")
#three backticks to close
````

I get this error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Unknown float option `H'.
```

I've tried each argument by itself, but it only runs if I remove the whole line.

Is there a way around this? I want to use render so I can dynamically generate the filename - maybe there is a better way?

Comment: Try adding `header-includes:
   - \usepackage{float}` to beginning part with the title, authors, etc. and see if it does anything

Comment: that gives me another error: 
```! Undefined control sequence.
<argument>  \begin {tabular}{lcccccc} \toprule 
                                               & mpg & cyl & disp & hp & dra...
l.85 \end{tabular}}
```

Comment: Try `header-includes:    - \usepackage{float}     - \usepackage{booktabs}`

Comment: another error:
```! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \cellcolor 
```

Comment: Loading the package colortbl, does seem to work, Actually. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Thanks to [Stacker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14404231/stacker). The solution is to load the required packages in the YAML:

```
header-includes:
  \usepackage{float}
  \usepackage{booktabs}
  \usepackage{colortbl}
```

The error changes each time.